# dwarf fortress (34.11) does not run, no error message

Tags: games, macbook

When I try to run Dwarf Fortress, nothing happens. Ubutnu 12.10 running on Macbook 4,1. When I try to run `df` on Terminal, the Terminal window pops open for a fraction of a second and then disappears, with no error message. I see someone else had a similar problem but got an error message. What might I be missing here? How to diagnose and fix? Thanks much.